# Bulk updating product prices : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, database, product-prices, bulk

> In my M2 store I have over 200k products. They were added manually
>   through API (`https://domain.com/rest/all/V1/products` call).

Nowadays prices of my products are changing frequently and I need to update all of them when I receive price list from my supplier.

What would be the best and quickest way to update prices of all my products? API calls would take too much time.

CSV import using M2 backend was giving me some errors in the past due to large amount of products.

Any idea? One think which comes to my mind is to write a php script to parse my price list CSV file and make directly SQL queries to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Magmi to Bulk updating product prices in Magento 2. Magmi is import product data fast and direct on database.

Download from URL:https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/tree/82ae373630c5291fc72ce948935916a811dc4f8b

Please referee sample CSV file for product price update.

```
sku     price
PR-MB01   31
PR-MX02   32
PR-UG04   94
PR-UG05   100
```